# Relation between Lebesgue measure and nowhere denseness

Tags: metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

As the title suggests, I am intereseted in knowing some relations between Lebesgue measures and the property of being nowhere dense, for subsets of **R**. An easy reult is that:
**Any closed set with 0 Lebesgue measure must be nowhere dense.** I want to know of some relations that are not so trivial, like the above! Thanks in advance.